# SwiftUI List not recognizing object type

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I'm trying to make a List in SwiftUI like this:

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    var piis = [IDPiece]()

    var body: some View {
        List(piis, id: \.identifier) { pii in
            Text( pii.label )
        }
    }
}
```

where `IDPiece` looks like:

```
struct IDPiece: Equatable {
    init() {}

    init(claim: Claim) {
        self.document = claim.document
        self.identifier = claim.identifier
        self.claimUID = claim.claimUID
        self.label = claim.label
    }

    var document: DocumentType = .na
    var identifier: String = ""
    var claimUID: String = ""
    var label: String?
}
```

But I keep receiving the following error on the line where I initialize the list:

> Type '_' has no member 'identifier'

It doesn't seem to be parsing the type of object contains in my `piis` list. Anyone know why that may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SwiftUI compiler errors are generally useless (this will improve over time, but today they're useless). Your problem has nothing to do with `\.identifier`. The problem is you have an optional `.label`, but you don't handle the case where it's nil. Almost certainly you should just make `label` non-optional. But if it needs to be optional (if you treat nil differently than empty in some place), then you need to do something about that, such as:

```
Text(pii.label ?? "N/A")
```

Comment: Lol, I can't believe that actually fixed it... I thought i had tried hard coding the value in the text and it hadn't worked but I guess I had some other error when i tried that. Anyway thanks, that did solve the problem